# 식식하게 or 씩씩하게 목소리 높여? Which did I hear in a song?

Tags: vocabulary, pronunciation, lyrics

I was streaming Korean music, and unfortunately, the stream doesn't have a good way to identify songs, singers, nor lyrics.

To answer my question, it might be necessary to hear the song, but in lieu of that, let me describe what I can (I don't have a link nor a title for the song).

A smooth voiced female, happily sang a song (about the speed and familiarity as compared to [*Don't Worry Be Happy*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVz4TaxMjYAhUD6CYKHfOwAVkQyCkIKjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dd-diB65scQU&usg=AOvVaw21LU97IxkpvSZ18xq5WIeZ).  I was a song that sounded encouraging, and it was filled with imperatives (like suggestions).  Each suggestion started with the same phrase.

I should have written down more of the lyrics, but she continually repeated, in each line...

> **씩씩하게** <...*Infinitive Tensed Verb*...>

for instance, she definitely sang these words in one of the imperative suggestions:

> **씩씩하게** 목소리 높여

---

Using both [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#ko/en/%EC%94%A9%EC%94%A9%ED%95%98%EA%B2%8C%20%EB%AA%A9%EC%86%8C%EB%A6%AC%20%EB%86%92%EC%97%AC) and [Daum 사전](http://dic.daum.net/search.do?q=%EC%94%A9%EC%94%A9%ED%95%98%EA%B2%8C&dic=ee), I see that `씩씩하게` means "**bravely/valiantly/gallantly/vigorously**".

But I can't be certain she didn't sing `식식하게` for two reasons.

1. Google Translate indicates that `식식하게` means "in style" - that may have fit well in her lyrics
2. Her pronunciation had more of an "sh" sound to it, unlike how i've heard `씨` pronounced.

---

I'm asking

- please verify if it's 씩씩하게 and not 식식하게
- (if 씩씩하게) please help with the pronunciation question since I heard `씨` pronounced with an "sh" sound
- please provide examples of `씩씩하게` and `식식하게`
- *An out of the park answer might include a link to this song's lyrics (but that would probably be like hitting the lottery)*

Comment: As a rule of thumb, take anything Google Translate says with caution.  Because it is created by scouring the web for bilingual sentence pairs, it can easily learn typos and common mistakes as "correct" expressions.

Comment: agreed, i do.  i still like it for speed, and i can generally tell when it's not doing the right thing, and half of those times, i report back to google and contribute "the right thing" once i determine what that is from daum or a native speaker or some other verifiable source. in fact, it was daum that suggested "bravely/valiantly/gallantly/vigorously" while google just said "vigorously".

Comment: Google translate has so many errors for single words that I'm not sure if it's worth considering.  Case in point: https://translate.google.com/#en/ko/the (Apparently "the" means "그만큼", "...하면 할수록", or "...하면 할수록 그만큼 더".)

Answer (score 1):

[I actually just found it by googling around a bit.](https://music.bugs.co.kr/track/30697056?wl_ref=list_tr_08_ar)

Here are the lyrics:

아티스트:   **달동네왈츠**

앨범: **씩씩하게**

재생 시간: **04:02**

*(it wouldn't copy paste without losing formatting...so here is an image until i can straighten that out or type it all)*

[image]

좋지 않은 세상의 많은 것을 바꾸고 싶지만
사람들의 마음을 여는 일은 어렵기만 하지
너무 빨리 잊혀진 많은 것을 간직하고 싶지만
사람들의 마음을 얻는 일은 어렵기만 하지

힘이 들고 답답하지만 조금만 더 버티는 거야

씩씩하게 어깨를 펴고 씩씩하게 해보는 거야
씩씩하게 견디고 나면 오늘 하루가 큰 힘이 되지
씩씩하게 목소리 높여 씩씩하게 말하는 거야
씩씩하게 꿈꾸고 나면 믿고 싶은 세상에 다가가

너무 빨리 잊혀진 많은 것을 간직하고 싶지만
사람들의 마음을 얻는 일은 어렵기만 하지

힘이 들고 답답하지만 조금만 더 버티는 거야

씩씩하게 어깨를 펴고 씩씩하게 해보는 거야
씩씩하게 견디고 나면 오늘 하루가 큰 힘이 되지
씩씩하게 목소리 높여 씩씩하게 말하는 거야
씩씩하게 꿈꾸고 나면 믿고 싶은 세상에 다가가

씩씩하게 어깨를 펴고 씩씩하게 해보는 거야
씩씩하게 견디고 나면 오늘 하루가 큰 힘이 되지
씩씩하게 목소리 높여 씩씩하게 말하는 거야
씩씩하게 꿈꾸고 나면 믿고 싶은 세상에 다가가

씩씩하게